# Can Response UDP Connection?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, udp

I Receive Many UDP Connection From None IP Valid Devices With This Code:

```
receivingUdpClient = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(Port)
Dim byteBuffer As [Byte]() = receivingUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
```

Now I Want Response Data To Device After Receive Data

I use This Code

```
receivingUdpClient.Send(receiveBytes, 10)
```

Buy Recived This Error :
"The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you you need to use SendTo and ReceiveFrom methods instead of Send and Receive with UDP sockets.  That way, you can get the IP:port (endpoint) of the sender - so you can send the response back to that same address.  My VB is weak, so I'll give you a simple example in C#.

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[1500];
IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
EndPoint senderRemote = (EndPoint)sender;

EndPoint senderRemote;
int bytesReceived = socket.recvFrom(buffer, senderRemote);
// echo the message back to the sender
if (bytesReceived > 0)
    socket.sendTo(buffer, bytesReceived, senderRemote);
```

Comment: He is using UdpClient so there is no SendTo or ReceiveFrom.

Comment: In which case, he should call the "Connect" method before making the first Send.

Comment: Yes, or he needs to specify the remote enpoint in the call to Send.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `RemoteIpEndPoint` captures the address you received the data from.  To send data back to that host you need to pass that address (endpoint) to your call to `Send`.